# PHP : Doesn't fetch result

Tags: php, mysql

I got a list of id from 1 table . I recently make a few change to the table where i add another column(Active) for id activation . The table look like this

```
ID | name | active
---|------|-------
01 | Jack | 1
02 | Ben  | 1
```

The list show if the id is active , i use yellow bulb icon and if not active it show grey bulb icon . The problem i got is if i want to change the activation status of the id, it doesnt fetch the result(show only blank page).

**SQL**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM jobseeker";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
```

**INDEX PHP**

```
<td align="center"><?php if($row['active']) == '1'){ ?>
            <a href ="action.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" onclick="return confirm ('You want to deactivate ?\n\nNo ID: <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>')"><img src="images/on.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Deactivate" style="cursor:pointer" align="absbottom" /></a>
            <?php } if($row['active'] == '0'){ ?>
            <a href ="action.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" onclick="return confirm ('You want to activate ?\n\nNo ID: <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>')"><img src="images/off.png" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Activate" style="cursor:pointer" align="absbottom" /></a>
            <?php } ?></td>
```

**ACTION PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once "inc/db.php";
require_once "inc/tarikh.php";

if(isset($_GET['active'])){
    $status=$_GET['active'];
    $sql_status=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM jobseeker WHERE id =".$status);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_object($sql_status)){
            $st=$row->active;

            if($st=='0'){
                $status2=1;
                }
                else{
                    $status2=0;
                    }

$update=mysql_query("UPDATE jobseeker SET active = ".$status2. WHERE ID = ".$status);
     if($update){
           header("Location: jobseeker_list.php");
           }
           else{
              echo mysql_error();
              }
     }
?>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code ? Please help me out

Comment: You're missing at least one quote character in action.php. Also your code is wide open to SQL injection. And all `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Please consider switching to PDO instead.

Comment: @Arjan its still doesnt show any result

Comment: Small summary: What you are learning is already deprecated knowledge paired with a vulnerability (SQL Injection, as mentioned by @Arjan, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 1):

You are only providing `ID` as a parameter to `action.php`.

```
<a href ="action.php?ID=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"
```

But you are only checking for `$_GET['active']`

```
if(isset($_GET['active'])){
```

So the code within the if clause will never execute. I guess you want to use `$_GET['ID']` instead.

This has syntax errors (it should be obvious with the syntax highlighting)

```
$update=mysql_query("UPDATE jobseeker SET active = ".$status2." WHERE ID = ".$status);
                                                              ^- missing quote
```

And the usual advice: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions. Your code will stop working then. Don't write new code with the `mysql_*` functions, use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects instad. Also, take a look at prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: thank! it work , i'm still learning about `mysqli_*` and `PDO`

Comment: great!! now start learning stackoverflow and accept the answer as the correct one ;)